# How to choose the background keyboard?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I work on a custom keyboard (My Keyboard is no xib or StoryBoard),

I want to know if I can choose the background to remain constant
according to the choice The custom keyboard on

For example: When I choose the keyboard to keyboard Dark then stay in the selected mode "Dark".

And when I want to change the background again to be in the Light then again to stay in the selected mode "Light".

This would look like:

> KeyboardInputTraits.swift

```
  func pollTraits() {
    if let proxy = (self.textDocumentProxy as? UITextInputTraits) {
        if let layout = self.layout {
            let appearanceIsDark = (proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark)
            if appearanceIsDark != layout.darkMode {
                self.updateAppearances(appearanceIsDark)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> KeyboardViewController.swift

```
func darkMode() -> Bool {
var darkMode = { () -> Bool in
    if let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy as? UITextDocumentProxy {
        return proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}()

return darkMode
```

}

Comment: So what is your issue?

Comment: I want to change my keyboard background
Maybe you can do me please my brother I have been almost a month trying to make it
I'm new IOS Developer and perhaps I did not explain well my question, but if we can talk by email or twitter I could explain it better by photographs and examples of existing applications

Comment: That exactly is the content you should provide in your post.

Comment: It's part of my code ...
I want to know if i can other colors
Or instead of this road to be on the background image